# A way to solve the problem "the terminal process failed to launch: path to shell executable "dotnet" does not exist."

Tags: .net, linux, visual-studio-code, archlinux

I recently received the following error when i initiated debug with .NET 6 on my VSCode (Arch Linux):

```
the terminal process failed to launch: path to shell executable "dotnet" does not exist.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to fix it:

- Install .NET Core via `sudo pacman -S dotnet-sdk` (this package isn't the last update, so this package doesn't work to build some projects and VSCode gets you an error of .NET Framework version)
- Download the last .NET Core package from [Official Microsoft Site (choose your binary version)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)
- Delete all files and folders from .NET Arch installation folder (if you don't know where is the installation folder, type `which dotnet` on your terminal to find it, usually the installation folder are in the path `/usr/share/dotnet`)
- Unpack your .NET Last version package in .NET Arch folder:
  `tar zxf dotnet-sdk-6.0.301-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet`
- Verify if in your `/usr/bin/` path have a binary of the dotnet
- Verify your task.json file in .vscode folder on your workspace folder, it should have the default configuration

**Ps.:** This VSCode problem happened to me with Arch Linux.